# How to store a string in image type column in SQL Server Using SqlParameter

Tags: sql-server, string, image, sqlparameter

I have a SQL Server database, and I want to store in image type column some string.

I'm trying to do the following :

```
SqlParameter myparam = new SqlParameter("@myparam", "VeryLongString");
myparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
```

when I add it to the command and then execute it, I get the following error :

> Failed to convert parameter value
>   from a String to a Byte[]

What seems to be the problem ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Image field in SQL Server stores a byte array (the bytes that make up the image), not a string.

If you're truly trying to pass in a very long string, you should use [`SqlDbType.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx).

Comment: Plus, the `IMAGE` datatype has been deprecated with SQL Server 2005 - if you need large text, use VARCHAR(MAX) - if you nee large binary storage, use VARBINARY(MAX).